# Why don't selectors need to pass arguments to methods that take parameters?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arguments, parameter-passing, selector

I'm looking into a project, trying to get a grip on the code. I just ran in to a `#selector`. As far as I understand it, `selectors` call methods (I'm sure there's more to it, of course).

One thing that struck me is that the `selector` call doesn't pass an `argument` to the `method` even though the `method` itself takes a `parameter`. The code works fine, so I take it that this is normal behavior with a `selector`. Here is a sample of the code:

```
[Communication sendVerifyNumber:ps.address verificationCode:@""
             withCallbackMethod:@selector(numberVerificationCallCompleted:)
             callbackFailMethod:@selector(numberVerificationCallFailed:) onObject:self];
}
```

And the `numberVerificationCallCompleted`:

```
-(void)numberVerificationCallCompleted:(NSNumber*)responseNumber{...}
```

So, my question is, is this a thing with `selectors`. I mean, is that why they are used? And how does it work? The `method` still needs an `argument` to work properly, so it has to come from somewhere, right?

Comment: A selector describes a "method" within an Object.  It doesn't call it, therefore you don't pass parameters to it.

Comment: @trojanfoe Could you elaborate on what you mean by "describes"? If it doesn't actually call and run the method, what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 2):

A selector *describes* a method within an Objective-C class, allowing you to call it at a later point in time.  Parameters are passed when it's called, not when it's described.

You store selectors in a [`SEL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/sel) type and call them using [`performSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418867-performselector?language=objc) making them ideal to use as callbacks.

The method you show above, will do something like this:

```
- (void)sendVerifyNumber:(NSString*)address
        verificationCode:(NSString*)verificationNumber
      withCallbackMethod:(SEL)callbackMethod
      callbackFailMethod:(SEL)failedCallbackMethod
                onObject:(id)callbackObject
{
    BOOL success = doWhateverIDo();
    if (success) {
        [callbackObject performSelector:callbackMethod
                             withObject:someArgumentToPassback];
    } else {
        [callbackObject performSelector:failedCallbackMethod
                             withObject:someArgumentToPassback];
    }
}
```

Note: you can only call a method that is described by a selector if it takes zero, one or two parameters (using `performSelector:`, `performSelector:withObject:` and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` respectively).

Comment: You can, however, call any arbitrary selector if you move away from `performSelector:...` (I know you know this, but that last sentence parsed otherwise in my head).

Comment: Actually @bbum I'm not sure I do know :)  How else would you call a selector other than `performSelector:`?

Comment: Call `objc_msgSend()` directly;  just type cast it correctly first.  Or `NSInvocation`.